# Pagination for image field in one node page

Tags: theming, entities, paging

I made a custom node type with following fields:

- Title
- Body
- Image (Unlimited)

I need to have a few pages from this content type and on each page I need to print the title field, the body and all images, but I need a pagination for the image field - lets say 9 images per page. (pagination only for one field in current node).

Is that possible without using Views, and using theming? For example, making a custom "field--field-images.tpl.php" template file, but instead of using the following code, printing the field with Pagination.

```
foreach ($items as $delta => $item): 
  print render($item);
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CCK Pager](http://drupal.org/project/cck_pager) project.

> CCK Pager allows to page the item list of any CCK field with multiple values.
>
> The module extends others CCK formatter by paging the field item list; setting the number of elements per page and pager type (full or mini) can be made per field.
>   It only works with versions of CCK >= 6.x-2.5.

Look at [this demonstration](http://www.psegno.it/cck_pager_photogallery), and if you are using Drupal 7, follow the status of [these issues](http://drupal.org/project/issues/cck_pager?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=7.x&component=All).

Comment: Thank you for quick replay.
Yes I am using Drupal 7 (sorry I didn't mention it).
The Demonstration is exacly what I am looking for

Comment: @Ivailo Milenkov: If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution compatible with Drupal 7, a good alternative to CCK Pager would be to embed a view that prints the paginated field content, as pointed out in [this blog post](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/creating-ajax-node-field-pager-embedded-contextual-view).